# not getting the dart file excecuted

Tags: flutter, android-studio

actually when we open any a new flutter project then we automatically get the main.dart file but in my case in did not get any file like that and moreover if I create it and copy paste the demo home page default code its not running and showing

I want the main.dart file to open automatically and when we click on run then it should open in the emulator

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Enter this in your terminal:

```
flutter pub get
```